# Gnuplot gif 3d plate

Tags: 3d, gnuplot

for my mini-thesis, I was told to do a gif of a simulation. the thesis itself is about low-velocity impacts onto a plate.

I haven't really started yet but tried to figure out how to plot it eventually.

Basically I have a function $z(x,y,t)$ and I want to plot it like this:

[image]

I have multiple questions for this task:

---

#### 1. When generating the data and writing it to the output file, how should I write the data?

I could either use one row for the x and y data and let all the z data follow:

```
x1 y1 z(t1) z(t2) z(t3) ....
x2 y2 z(t1) z(t2) z(t3) ....
...
```

Or I could do it this way:

```
x1 y1 z(t1)
x2 y2 z(t1)
...

x1 y1 z(t2)
x2 y2 z(t2)
...
```

If I would use the second way, how would it be best for me to seperate the data for each timestep? Is one space enough?

#### How could I plot the data?

I looked at other posts here to check if someone did something similar but I would be very happy if someone could give me some advice on some data output scheme and how to use it in gnuplot.

I am very happy for any help!

Greetings,
Finn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess it is a matter of taste and how you generate the data.

**Case 1:**

```
x1 y1 z(t1) z(t2) z(t3) ....
x2 y2 z(t1) z(t2) z(t3) ....
...
```

**Case 2:**

```
x1 y1 z(t1)
x2 y2 z(t1)
...

x1 y1 z(t2)
x2 y2 z(t2)
...
```

For Case 1 the data file would be more compact compared to Case 2 because you don't list identical x and y multiple times.

**Plotting case 1:**

```
splot 'myData.dat' u 1:2:3 , '' u 1:2:4, '' u 1:2:5
```

or

```
splot for [i=3:5] 'myData.dat' u 1:2:i
```

**Plotting case 2:** (if you separate with exactly 1 empty line). Check `help every`

```
splot 'myData.dat' u 1:2:3 every :::0::0, '' u 1:2:3 every :::1::1, '' u 1:2:3 every :::2::2
```

or

```
splot for [i=0:2] 'myData.dat' u 1:2:3 every :::i::i
```

**Plotting case 2:** (if you separate with 2 (or more) empty lines). Check `help index`.

```
splot 'myData.dat' u 1:2:3 index 0, '' u 1:2:3 index 1, '' u 1:2:3 index 2
```

or

```
splot for [i=0:2] 'myData.dat' u 1:2:3 index i
```

Comment: great answer! Thank you very much! This is exactly what i was looking for :)